# Linux Kernel Debugging: "Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> There is no member named module_core." when trying to use helper scripts in gdb

Tags: python, linux-kernel, gdb, kernel

I've been following [this guide](http://www.alexlambert.com/2017/12/18/kernel-debugging-for-newbies.html) to set up a Linux kernel debugging environment with gdb and VMWare.
Everything went on smoothly until that part:

> **Connect GDB to the debuggee**
>   We won’t be able to see symbols from loaded kernel modules yet. We’ll load the helper script and then run lx-symbols, which will probe the loaded modules and configure GDB appropriately:
>   `(gdb) source home/alambert/kernel/source/linux-4.13.0/debian/build/build-generic/vmlinux-gdb.py`
>   `(gdb) lx-symbols`

When running this on my system I get the following python error:
`pwndbg> source /home/user/kernel/source/linux-4.4.0/debian/build/build-generic/vmlinux-gdb.py 
pwndbg> lx-symbols
loading vmlinux
Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> There is no member named module_core.: 
Error occurred in Python command: There is no member named module_core.`

---

### My setup

Both the *debugger* and *debugee* machines are VMs, the debugee is a Ubuntu 16.04 and the debugger is a Ubuntu 18.04.

**Debugee:**
`$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.0-134-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-033) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) ) #160-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 14:58:00 UTC 2018`

**Debugger:**
`$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.15.0-34-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-047) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018
$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.2
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ python -V
Python 2.7.15rc1`

---

I first thought it was a python3/2 compatibility issue so I recompiled gdb with python 2.7, but got the exact same error.

I have also verified it is not a `pwndbg` problem - I tried this with vanilla gdb to the exact same effect.

I have verified that the python helper scripts had been created in the process of compiling the debugee kernel. I actually let the whole build process complete rather than stopping it once the scripts were created like the guide suggests - just to make sure all of them are in place.

I have tried looking for the error online but there does not seem to be any mention of it.

Did anybody ever encounter that problem?

Comment: Could you please type `(gdb) set python print-stack full` , then enter that `source` command again, and edit your question to include the full backtrace that is displayed?

Comment: Thank you very much Mark, I have managed to solve the issue. As I discovered, this was not a python bug but rather an inconsistency between the  `module.h` header and the helper script. Thanks again for the quick response!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some digging in the sources of the scripts and the linux kernel, I have managed to fix the issue.

The problem lies in [this commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/7523e4dc5057e157212b4741abd6256e03404cf1#diff-1e0f958766bae7c6dcd60e895c0531c5) which replaced the `module_core` pointer with a `module_layout` struct in the `include/linux/module.h` header. The change had been apparently pulled into kernel 4.4.0 but was not accounted for in the helper scripts until a later version.

This had been dealt with a while later (specifically - in [this commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ad4db3b24a93e52a92ad8f9b0273a9416f202c23#diff-761b044bd5c035a2cc9bbf445aab2adf)), so all kernel versions between 4.4.0 and 4.6-rc1 will have this bug.

The solution is to download the scripts from the aforementioned [commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/ad4db3b24a93e52a92ad8f9b0273a9416f202c23/scripts/gdb) and place them in the relevant directories.

This is certainly a rare edge-case but I hope this answer will be helpful to somebody someday.